# Launch python script with command line arguments

Tags: python, command-line, serial-port, arduino, communication

I'd like to execute this script, passing arguments from the command line:

```
import serial
import sys

try:
  ser = serial.Serial("COM7", 9600)
except serial.SerialException:
  print("Exception...")


if sys.argv[1] == "on":
   ser.write("m".encode('latin1'))
   print("Light on...")
elif sys.argv[1] == "off":
   ser.write("n".encode('latin1'))
   print("Light off...")

ser.close()
```

The serial device doesn't get the character sent through serial communication if the script were launched from command line:

```
C:\users\user\Desktop\seriale.py on
```

Launching it through the python IDLE (removing the sys.argv sure) works and the serial device gets the data as it should. What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the "python_path" in the enviornment variable. Preferbly adding the location where python is installed in the PATH variable will solve your issue.

Comment: I said the issue was the information not received on the serial device, not the executing a python script by command line.

By the way, putting a while True with input() sending the input over serial works! The problem seems to be with the single instruction ser.write("x".encode('latin1'))
Using a loop the shell always remains opened... hmm help!

Comment: No, if the information is not received on the serial device, the python script by command line is likely not operating correctly. The shell closes because the program stops running, by nature a while loop will keep the program running, and the shell running.

Comment: This is almost certainly a Windows permissions error, as windows will not let certain programs access COM ports. I have had similar issues using java - a java program running from the IDE can access the ports properly, but running the unsigned JAR file directly disables the COM ports. I would recommend what Lonely said, adding it to PATH may allow the COM port to be opened.

Comment: Solution founded:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301127/pyserial-app-runs-in-shell-by-not-py-script?rq=1

You gotta put some sleep function before sending command through serial.