# PySerial doesn't work in script

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, arduino, pyserial

I have problem with this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600, timeout=1)
ser.write("test")
print "Test started\n"
time.sleep(1)
ans = ser.read(4)
print ans
```

In Arduino is echo program (everything what has been sent to Arduino has been sent back to computer). With serial monitor everything works fine.

When I'm running my python script it stops on ser.read() (it is waiting for incoming data). But when commands from my script I've written directly to python console everything works without problems.

Why my code started from file didn't work?

My OS: Windows 8.1 (64 bits)
Python version: 2.7.9 (64 bits)

Comment: Did you remember to code an `write` in your Arduino code? Can you post your Arduino code here?

Comment: Is your arduino looking for a new line at the end of the write? E.g. `ser.write("test\n")`.

Comment: @MauroBaraldi
Here is my Arduino code. 

<code>
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) 
    Serial.write(Serial.read());
}
</code>

Comment: @figs It doesn't matter. Arduino should response for every character.

Comment: @bigben as a debug, you could blink a led every time you receive data in Arduino. Maybe you're mapping wrong port

Comment: @MauroBaraldi

My new code:

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);  
    Serial.write(Serial.read());
  }
}

LED is turn on before data were received. When something was sent to Arduino diode is turning off. 

When I'm starting script from file, diode for short moment is off, but when script is waiting for data from Arduino diode is turning on.

I'm sorry for few new comments but edit option is disabled here after 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600, timeout=1)
ser.write("test")
print "Test started - data sent \n"
while True:
    ans = ser.read(4)
    if and:
        print and
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: insert a `pdb` debug statement just after `while` and try to investigate.

Comment: Thanks for help but I've solution here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301127/pyserial-app-runs-in-shell-by-not-py-script) . Trick with setDTR works in my case.