# pySerial very strange behaviour ... Code works when executed in shell but not in a script

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm struggling with pySerial. To be brief ... The code below works great when executed in the Python Shell ...

```
>>> import serial
>>> s=serial.Serial("COM5", 9600)
>>> while(1):
       s.write("#")
       s.readline()
```

Produces the output below in the shell:

```
1L
'56.73\r\n'
1L
'56.73\r\n'
```

When the same code is written in a script say "readSerial.py" the script will either not transmit the hashtag that triggers the serial device to transmit the data, or will not receive the replied data.

I'm using pySerial 3, but have noticed the same behavior with 2.7. Using Python 2.7.10 64 bit on Win10. But also noticed this behavior on Raspberry Pi with /dev/ttyACM0. I would really like to have this solved. I'm not that experienced in Python so this might be an oversight.

Hardware is checked and double checked.

Thanks,

KK

---

Thanks, but I really know how to print data from Python. The problem is really with pySerial. Here is the complete code, please don't discus errors in commented out code. These are of no concern here.

```
#from numpy import array
#import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time
import serial as s

#data = array([])

Arduino = s.Serial("COM5", 9600)
i = 0

while (1):
    try:
         Arduino.write("#")
         time.sleep(.1)
         inString = Arduino.readline()
         data = float(inString)

         print i, ":", data
         i += 1

         time.sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

Arduino.close()
```

But like said this doesn't work. As far as I can tell the readline() function does not return. And ... there 's really no point in making it return by setting the tx timeout. To add to the mistery; When the code is debugged (i.e. stepped trough) it does work.

Thanks in advance,

KK

Comment: I don't see how that code produces _any_ shell output at all.  It has no print statements.

Comment: @John I think he is talking about output on the Pi, which is probably connected on COM5 (I know that's how it'd work with Arduino at least). @K What have you tried so far? A quick google search shows up a lot of results for similar issues e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301127/pyserial-app-runs-in-shell-by-not-py-script

Comment: Even so, the only output that happens is `s.write("#")`, and I don't see how that can translate into the supposed given output.

Comment: @John, It is connected to an arduino at COM5 but that 's of no concern. In the script there are plenty of print statements. The arduino replies on the hashtag with data from a sensor and a windows line termination. It is the readline() or read() functions that never return when called, although data is received.

Comment: @whrrgarbl I took a second look at the link you posted ... There are indeed a lot of simular posts but I never found one that solves the problem ... The one I like the most is "pySerial just doesn't work on Windows AMD64" or "Computers are just to fast" I've noticed the same behaviour on Raspbian Linux on a Raspberry Pi B. You can tell a lot about the RPi, but it isn't fast.

Comment: From @whrrgarbl posted links, try sleeping before sending the hash. Seems like windows resets the arduino when opening the com port. It also explains why it work on interactive mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/appendix.html#how-to) :

> **Example works in serial.tools.miniterm but not in script.**
>
> **The RTS and DTR lines are switched when the port is opened.** This may
>   cause some processing or reset on the connected device. In such a
>   cases an immediately following call to write() may not be received by
>   the device.
>
> A **delay after opening the port, before the first write()**, is
>   recommended in this situation. E.g. a time.sleep(1)

Comment: I read the faq. Nope, this is not the case ... But to narrow the problem further down. I 've tried bridging the Tx and Rx lines on a FTDI USB to serial converter from Arduino -> the script works like charm but it is indexed at COM4. When I take the same software and a Mega2560 (indexed at COM4) the script works like a charm!

Comment: Wow this is the hardest Forum software I've ever encountered, can't edit my previous post. To the point at hand: Actually reading your answer again and fiddling around with the sleep time after the serial object is created the problem is solved. I have some original Italian Arduino stuff laying around, that all works like charm with even very short delays. Unfortunately, I also have a few cheap Chinese knock-offs    (i.e. Infiduino Uno R3) these need delays of  2 seconds.

Comment: You can edit *comments* for 5 mins.  After that you can always copy/erase/paste with modifications.  You can edit *questions* and  *answers* without a time limit.

Comment: Yeah, I should have left a note why I posted lines from the faq.  The original code didn't have a delay between opening and the 1st write.

Comment: Intel's Genuino 101 works like a charm without delay, all depends on the USB Serial interface.