# pyserial works in repl but not script

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm attempting to write data to an arduino using pyserial on windows. However, I've run into a bit of a snag that I can't seem to figure out. I can run:

```
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial('com3',9600)
>>> ser.write(b'0')
```

and it works perfectly fine on the repl but not when I run it in a script. The entirity of the script text being:

```
import serial


if __name__=="__main__":
    ser = serial.Serial('com3',9600)
    print("yes, this is being called")
    ser.write(b'0')
```

and it really has me baffled. has anyone dealt with anything like this?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same python when running repl and script ? Maybe you have a virtualenv which is kicking in ?

Comment: See this other question, seems to be a FAQ. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878750/pyserial-very-strange-behaviour-code-works-when-executed-in-shell-but-not-in?rq=1

Comment: Thank you @Tomuo! I googled around but didn't find much that was helpful, I didn't have the right keywords apparently.